# Hadoop calling the wrong API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am tying to do a simple map reduce function in Hadoop 2.3.0 using the  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce API and yet when I try to to run it I get the following error

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit.
```

Since what I call in the mapreduce function I am using is this

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
```

I have no idea why it keeps using the old API, is there some configuration file I have modify?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes` command to refesh the nodes. So that it will fetch new API.

Comment: Does that command work in 2.3.0? Because I keep getting DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Comment: Please refer below link for more information :
`http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#dfsadmin`

Comment: Never mind, I run the command hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes. However the API error still remains.